# Whatsapp Share link not pushing/opening to whatsapp

Tags: php, html, whatsapp

I cant seem to get the link to actually push into whatsapp

```
 <a  href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $watext ?> <?php echo $x ?>" target="_blank">Whatsapp</a>
```

I can see the actual outputs on the url it just doesnt push to open whatsapp

```
whatsapp://send?text=Have a look at Somethingsomeoneatsomeplace
```

Anyone maybe any ideas?

Comment: The ```whatsapp://send?text=``` Is Depricated they use: ```https://wa.me/?text=``` Now it seems That or maybe its because the whatsapp doesnt include the https testing a bit more Edit: https On whatsapp:// send doesnt assist It just seems the link is no linger in use and they use wa.me now

Answer (score 1):

**Appropriate(Correct) Link is**: https://wa.me/?

Not

`Whatsapp://send?`

This seems to be an older version of the link but i'd love to hear if there is more of a difference between the to and why the one works but not the other.